# How to change color based on formula result?

Tags: excel, vba

I made a macro, that changes the color of specific characters in a range of cells.

The macro works if the cell content is written manually.

I want the macro to read the formula result in the range instead, because the cells will have different combinations of x, y and 7 according to a user defined function (a bunch of if-statements).

The macro is showing wrong colors, when the cell content is not manually written.

I tried a time delay for my macro, so it would execute after my user defined function, because I thought my macro maybe executed before. That didn't work. That's why I think the problem is that the macro doesn't read the formula result.

```
Public Sub ChangeColor()
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim FarveZ As Integer
    Dim FarveX As Integer
    Dim Farve7 As Integer

    Set MyRange = Range("G32:R34")  

    FarveZ = 26   
    FarveX = 46   
    Farve7 = 3   

    For Each tempstring In MyRange
        If tempstring = "zx7" Then
            tempstring.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=1).Font.ColorIndex = FarveZ
            tempstring.Characters(Start:=2, Length:=1).Font.ColorIndex = FarveX
            tempstring.Characters(Start:=3, Length:=1).Font.ColorIndex = Farve7
        ElseIf tempstring = "zx" Then
            tempstring.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=1).Font.ColorIndex = FarveZ
            tempstring.Characters(Start:=2, Length:=1).Font.ColorIndex = FarveX
        ElseIf tempstring = "z7" Then
            tempstring.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=1).Font.ColorIndex = FarveZ
            tempstring.Characters(Start:=2, Length:=1).Font.ColorIndex = Farve7
        ElseIf tempstring = "x7" Then
            tempstring.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=1).Font.ColorIndex = FarveX
            tempstring.Characters(Start:=2, Length:=1).Font.ColorIndex = Farve7
        ElseIf tempstring = "z" Then
            tempstring.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=1).Font.ColorIndex = FarveZ
        ElseIf tempstring = "x" Then
            tempstring.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=1).Font.ColorIndex = FarveX
        ElseIf tempstring = "7" Then
            tempstring.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=1).Font.ColorIndex = Farve7
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next tempstring

End Sub
```

I don't get any error messages. It just doesn't come up with the right colors.

Comment: Since `tempstring` is not a string, but a range, the name is quite misleading IMO. BTW `tempstring` doesn't seem declared, is it somewhere else in the code?

Comment: Hello, not it's actually not declared. I'm a newbie when it comes to VBA. I tried to declare it as a string, but it didnt work. Should I declare it as a range?

Comment: Yes, it is not a string, either a variant or a range. You might want to replace all of your `If... Then ... End If` block by a `Select Case` structure, it will probably be more readable. And use tempstring.Value2 to evaluate the value.

Comment: Also, another great tool when you are beginning with VBA is to use `Option Explicit` at the start of any module.  This will force you to declare all variables.

Comment: Thank you. I declared tempstring as a variant now. And I'm using Option Explitcit and tempstring.Value2. I will also see if I can use a Select Case structure. However even with Value2 is still not working.

Comment: The issue you're having is that while the *value* of the cell is being tested correctly, you are colouring individual cell characters - You can't apply colour manually to part of a formula - so a macro is also unlikely to be able to do this.

Comment: Ah, okay. I'm making this as a part of an interactive Gantt chart, so I have to keep the formula in the cells (the letters z,x and 7 will turn into symbols with Wingdings). But would it be an idea if I made another macro that could copy the cell content and paste it as 'written values' in a new range, so this color-changing macro could read that new range?

Comment: Hi Christina - that would certainly solve the problem. You could make the copying of the cell part of your loop. I'll post an answer that does this in a moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comments, the following routine, tweaked and adjusted from your own - will create a copy of your formula results, 10 rows below that is colour coded as per your code.

You can even hide the rows 32-34 if you like, the coding can still 'see' the values and will still work fine.

```
Public Sub ChangeColor()
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim FarveZ As Integer
    Dim FarveX As Integer
    Dim Farve7 As Integer
    Dim Rowoffset As Long

    Set MyRange = Range("G32:R34")

    Rowoffset = 10 ' change this value to move the copy

    FarveZ = 26
    FarveX = 46
    Farve7 = 3

    For Each FormulaArea In MyRange
        Set OffsetData = FormulaArea.Offset(Rowoffset, 0)
        OffsetData.Value = FormulaArea.Value
        Select Case FormulaArea.Value
            Case "zx7"
                OffsetData.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=1).Font.ColorIndex = FarveZ
                OffsetData.Characters(Start:=2, Length:=1).Font.ColorIndex = FarveX
                OffsetData.Characters(Start:=3, Length:=1).Font.ColorIndex = Farve7
            Case "zx"
                OffsetData.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=1).Font.ColorIndex = FarveZ
                OffsetData.Characters(Start:=2, Length:=1).Font.ColorIndex = FarveX
            Case "z7"
                OffsetData.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=1).Font.ColorIndex = FarveZ
                OffsetData.Characters(Start:=2, Length:=1).Font.ColorIndex = Farve7
            Case "x7"
                OffsetData.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=1).Font.ColorIndex = FarveX
                OffsetData.Characters(Start:=2, Length:=1).Font.ColorIndex = Farve7
            Case "z"
                OffsetData.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=1).Font.ColorIndex = FarveZ
            Case "x"
                OffsetData.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=1).Font.ColorIndex = FarveX
            Case "7"
                OffsetData.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=1).Font.ColorIndex = Farve7
        End Select
    Next FormulaArea

End Sub
```

---

A slightly tidier way to do this would be testing based on just each character:

```
Public Sub ChangeColor_version2()
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim FarveZ As Integer
    Dim FarveX As Integer
    Dim Farve7 As Integer
    Dim Rowoffset As Long
    Dim x as Long

    Set MyRange = Range("G32:R34")
    'For multiple tabs, specify the sheet that contains the formulas:
    'Set MyRange = Sheets("existing_sheet_name").Range("G32:R34")

    Rowoffset = 10 ' change this value to move the copy

    FarveZ = 26
    FarveX = 46
    Farve7 = 3

    For Each FormulaArea In MyRange
        Set OffsetData = FormulaArea.Offset(Rowoffset, 0)

        ' For multiple tabs, specify the destination sheet in the setting of the OffsetData range like this:
        ' Set OffsetData = Sheets("other_sheet_name").Range("A1").Offset(Rowoffset + FormulaArea.Row, FormulaArea.Column)

        OffsetData.Value = "'" & FormulaArea.Value
        For x = 1 To Len(FormulaArea.Value)
            With OffsetData.Characters(Start:=x, Length:=1)
            Select Case .Text
                Case "z"
                    .Font.ColorIndex = FarveZ
                Case "x"
                    .Font.ColorIndex = FarveX
                Case "7"
                    .Font.ColorIndex = Farve7
            End Select
            End With
        Next
    Next FormulaArea

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! It's perfect! I think I will try to make the copy in a new sheet. If I hide that sheet will it still be able to read it?

Comment: Yes, that would work as well. See additional notes in the answer.